# How to install libuv on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, apt-get, libuv

sudo apt-get install libuv

```
$ sudo apt-get install libuv
[sudo] username ...
It fails to find package and install.
```

Is libuv included in some other packages?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `apt-cache search` to find packages. For example, on Ubuntu Yakkety the command `apt-cache search libuv` currently returns the following:

```
libuv0.10 - asynchronous event notification library - runtime library
libuv0.10-dbg - asynchronous event notification library - debugging symbols
libuv0.10-dev - asynchronous event notification library - development files
libuv1 - asynchronous event notification library - runtime library
libuv1-dbg - asynchronous event notification library - debugging symbols
libuv1-dev - asynchronous event notification library - development files
lua-luv - libuv bindings for lua
lua-luv-dev - libuv bindings for lua
```

Make sure your package cache is up to date by first running `apt-get update`!

Answer (score 5):

Install libuv on ubuntu 14.04 .

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:acooks/libwebsockets6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libuv1.dev
```